# How to force reloading custom function result?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I use this script to get the current sheet name :

```
function sheetName() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
}
```

then use `=sheetName()` in the cell to load the current sheet name. It works but if I rename the sheet, the script won't load the new name. In the setting, I already set the calculation to 'on change'. I tried to force refreshing using Google Apps Script by setting the value of the cell to `""` (blank) then re-set the cell with the same previous formula but it won't update immediately:

```
function refreshtest() {
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var quot_cell = "L11" // cell location where the formula is used to grab the sheet name
  var formula = Sheet.getRange(quot_cell).getFormula()
  Sheet.getRange(quot_cell).setValue("")
  Sheet.getRange(quot_cell).setValue(formula)

}
```

But it will load properly if I manually delete the formula and set it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) side-effect. Use a dummy parameter as demonstrated by my [SheetName()](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95595167?msgid=95630115) custom function. Make the dummy parameter point to some cell or range that changes often.